# Understanding wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

If $(X,x_0),(Y,y_0)$ are two pointed space then their wedge sum is defined as $X\sqcup Y/\{x_0,y_0\}.$

We are to show that, $X\sqcup Y/\{x_0,y_0\}\cong X×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times Y$

Consider the map, $f:X\sqcup Y/\{x_0,y_0\}\to X×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times Y$ defined as,
$f(x)=(x,y_0)$ if $x\in  X$ and $f(y)=(x_0,y)$ if $y\in Y.$

Clearly this map is bijective.
Next, to show that it's a homeomorphism we take a basis element $U\sqcup V$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in Y then, $f(U\sqcup V)=U×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}×V$ which is open in $X×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times Y$ and similarly for a basis element  $V×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times W$ where $V,W$ is open in $X,Y$ respectively ,we have $f^{-1}(V×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times W)=V\sqcup W$ which is open in $X\sqcup Y/\{x_0,y_0\}$ and hence the result follows.

Is my argument correct? If there is any shorter approach please mention.

Comment: The argument is correct. You are showing that your continuous bijection is an open map. Note that the analysis extends to finite wedges, but not to infinite wedges.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for infinite case?

Comment: Try it for a countable product of unit intervals (based at $0$, say). It's a good exercise in understanding the Tychonoff product topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument seems correct but there are some details that you need to be careful about. For example,

> $f:X\sqcup Y/\{x_0,y_0\}\to X×\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times Y$ defined as,
> $f(x)=(x,y_0)$ if $x\in  X$ and $f(y)=(x_0,y)$ if $y\in Y.$

why is this map well-defined? Note that, the elements of the quotient space $\left(X\sqcup Y\right)/\{x_0, y_0\}$ are equivalence classes.

Instead, we should define $f : X \sqcup Y \to X\times\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}\times Y$ as $z \mapsto \begin{cases} (z, y_0)  & \text{ if } z \in X \\ (x_0, z)  & \text{ if } z \in Y \end{cases}$.

We must show that this $f$ is constant on each equivalence class. The only non-trivial class is that of the basepoints $[x_0]=[y_0]$. Now, $f(x_0) = (x_0, y_0) = f(y_0)$. So, this map does descend to the quotient $\left(X\sqcup Y\right)/\{x_0, y_0\}$.

Clearly, the induced map is continuous and bijective.

For opennnes, let $U \subset \left(X\sqcup Y\right)/\{x_0, y_0\} $ be open. This means its preimage in $X \sqcup Y$ (under the quotient map) is open. So, we can write this preimage as $U_1 \sqcup U_2$, where $U_1$ is open in $X$ and $U_2$ is open in $Y$. So, the image of $U$ under $f$ is $U_1\times\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}\times U_2$ which is open in $X\times\{y_0\}\cup \{x_0\}\times Y$.

Comment: Yes! You are right.Thank you.